# Using ruby/nokogiri to transform xml to another xml

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I've never encountered task of transforming XML from one form to another. I hear that XSLT is just for that, but I don't want to go there. So, using only ruby and nokogiri, how can I:
**remove** all *item* **elements** but *time* from initial XML and also **rename element** *time* to *HammerTime*?
Initial XML:

```
...
<item>
  <time>05.04.2011 9:53:23</time>
  <iddqd>42</iddqd>
  <idkfa>woot</idkfa>
</item>
<item>
...
```

Desired result:

```
...
<item>
  <HammerTime>05.04.2011 9:53:23</HammerTime>
</item>
<item>
...
```

I figured out how to put data from XML to array using nokogiri's .xpath, but is there a way to make the desired transformation into another XML without manually having to write something like `puts "<HammerTime>#{array['time']}</HammerTime>"`?

Comment: The Nokogiri site has a [tutorial](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/modifying_an_html_xml_document.html) on doing this kind of thing. The docs are also quite filled with examples, for instance Nokogiri::XML::Node.

Comment: I've been all over XML::Node docs, but failed to understand how to do what I want. The tutorial you linked to also lacks the much wanted instructions.

Comment: Take it step by step. You want to rename a node. There's no rename method, but there are delete and add node methods, and methods for getting and setting content of a node. So you could do a copy + delete  + add.

Comment: You can rename nodes with Nokogiri, have a look at `Node#name=`. There is no need to copy/delete/add (that is easy to mistake).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML <<-EOHTML
<html>
  <body>
    <item>
      <time>05.04.2011 9:53:23</time>
      <iddqd>42</iddqd>
      <idkfa>woot</idkfa>
    </item>
  </body>
</html>
EOHTML

hammer = doc.at_css "time"
hammer.name = 'hammertime'
doc.css("iddqd").remove
doc.css("idkfa").remove

outfile = File.new("output.html", "w")
outfile.puts doc.to_html
outfile.close
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to do this in not HTML-oriented way?

Comment: I just wanted to show you an end to end example. That chunk of code would work on xml too. Nokogiri gives you the option of using css or xpaths: use whichever you're most comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with

> into another XML without manually having to write something like `puts "<HammerTime>#{array['time']}</HammerTime>"`?

If you want to transform an XML element into another in a language-independent way, you can use XSLT transformations (or stylesheet). Once you have your XSLT file you can apply it with Nokogiri's `Nokogiri::XSLT::Stylesheet#apply_to`.

Comment: By that I mean that I don't want to manually write all XML syntax of output XML.
... and I especially don't want to dig into XSLT.